# Angular(2+) template forms display error message in a <ul>

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I was trying out the angular forms out today and even though it works I cannot seem to get the validation logic right. What I actually want to do is that when a field will be incorrect it appaers on the top of the form with a message rendered in a <'ul'> <'li'> tag but only when the complete form has been filled out. Currently it shows the errors as soon as there will be a focus on the input boxes.

[image]

and finally here is my relevant code:

```
            <form #formAdd="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submit(formAdd)">

                <!-- error reporting-->

                    <ul *ngIf="!formAdd.valid && formAdd.dirty" class="alert alert-danger">
                        <li *ngIf="className.touched && !className.valid">
                            <span *ngIf="className.errors.required">Class name is required.</span>
                            <span *ngIf="className.errors.minlength">Class name should be at least 3 characters.</span>
                        </li>
                        <li *ngIf="maxStudents.touched && !maxStudents.valid">
                            <span *ngIf="maxStudents.errors.required">Maximum number of students is required.</span>
                        </li>
                    </ul>


                <div ngModelGroup="class">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="className">Class name:</label>
                        <input required
                               minlength="3"
                               ngModel
                               #className="ngModel"
                               name="className"
                               (change)="log(className)"
                               type="text"
                               class="form-control"
                               id="className" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="maxStudents">Max students:</label>
                        <input required  
                               ngModel 
                               #maxStudents="ngModel"
                               name="maxStudents" 
                               type="number" 
                               class="form-control" 
                               id="maxStudents">
                    </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!formAdd.valid">Submit</button>

                </div>
            </form>
```

Any help will be much appreciated, Cheers!

Comment: You're already doing two checks on your div. Why would it be different on a li? Your second question doesn't really make sense: you want to display a message saying that a field is required, but you want to display it only when all fields are filled. This is contradictory.

Comment: You are right, I think i wasn't of clear mind. I changed the div to a ul. however I only want the error pane showing when the whole form (including all it's  input elements) have been filled out.

Comment: Again, if it's been filled out, then you'll never be able to show `required` errors, and the code shows that you want to display those. So you're contradicting yourself. If a required error exists, it means the form has not been filled.